# Inserir dados em uma table com foreign key no ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, datatable

Vou tentar ser o mais objetivo possível então nem muitos códigos vou colocar (pois o original está realmente muito grande). Eu estou fazendo um progrma de cadastro simples que possui:
 - 1 `datagridview` para selecionar o cliente desejado em uma lista de registros
 - 1 `datagridview` dentro de uma `tabPage` para exibir os dados de nome e endereço do cliente selecionado, com inclusão, alteração e exclusão
 - 1 `datagridview` dentro de uma `tabPage` para exibir os dados de telefone do cliente selecionado, com inclusão, alteração e exclusão
 E para cada tabPage tem uma table criada no `SQL Server`, uma com os dados de nome e endereço e outra com o telefone (para adicionar mais de um para cada cliente).
 O que acontece é que eu pensei em pegar o `ID` do telefone

**Atualiação:** Quando eu vou cadastrar um novo cliente, tenho os dados das duas `dataGridView` que estão dentro de duas `tabPage` para preencher. Na page 1 de informações como nome e endereço e na page 2 a informação do telefone, que pode ser um ou mais de um (que podem ser visualizados na `dataGridView` dessa page). Eu usei a chave estrangeira para conectar os `ID`s do cliente nas duas `tables` mas não estou conseguindo inserir novos números de telefone.

Para exemplificar a parte relevante do código para incluir o telefone é esse:

```
objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
objComm = new SqlCommand(strCommtblTel, objConn);
objComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblTelefone (Telefone) values (@Telefone)";


try
{
    objConn.Open();

    objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", txt_telefone.Text);

    dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "tblTelefone");

    objComm.ExecuteNonQuery(); //retorna o número de linhas afetadas 
    dataSet.Clear(); //limpa os dados no dataSet
    objConn.Close(); //encerra a conexão com o banco de dados 

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}


private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        txt_nome.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Nome"].Value.ToString();
        txt_endereco.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Endereço"].Value.ToString();

    }

}

private void dgvTable_Cliente_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    numLinha = dgvTable_Cliente.CurrentRow.Index;
    clienteID = dgvTable_Cliente.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
    IDCli_atual = clienteID;

    txt_nome.Text = dgvTable_Cliente.CurrentRow.Cells["Nome"].Value.ToString();
    txt_endereco.Text = dgvTable_Cliente.CurrentRow.Cells["Endereço"].Value.ToString();

}


private void dgvTable_Contato_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    txt_telefone.Text = dgvTable_Contato.CurrentRow.Cells["Telefone"].Value.ToString();

    contatoID = dgvTable_Contato.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
}

//***********
```

O problema que eu estou tendo é que não consigo adicionar novos telefones e nem nada mais além disso pois eu preciso pegar o `ID` do telefone, e gostaria de uma ajuda nisso pois o que eu estou tentando nao está dando certo.

Comment: Você tem o id do cliente?

Comment: Sua pergunta não é ruim, mas esta faltando informação para entende melhor, veja bem, você tem o id cliente e esta buscando todos os telefones dele? se você vai alterar um desses telefones que já esta salvo então automaticamente você já terá o id dele. Agora se você esta tentando criar um novo telefone e salva no banco terá que informa o ID do cliente no insert.  Outra coisa não entendi o que você faz com o dataAdapter.Update ???? Edite sua pergunta com  mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade voce precisa passar o codigo do cliente que voce quer associar ao telefone que voce esta inserindo, com base no seu codigo voce precisa fazer isso:

Inserir o campo `ID` na sua string de INSERT.

```
objComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblTelefone (Telefone, ID) values (@Telefone, @ID)";
```

depois voce precisa atribuir o valor pra esse parametro, pegando de onde se encontra o ID do cliente no seu codigo..

```
objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", contatoID.ToString());
```

Aqui a versão final do seu código usando como ex um textBox( que voce pode trocar pelo cliente selecionado na sua grid).

```
objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
objComm = new SqlCommand(strCommtblTel, objConn);
objComm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblTelefone (Telefone, ID) values (@Telefone, @ID)";


try
{
    objConn.Open();

    objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefone", txt_telefone.Text);
    objComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", contatoID.ToString());

    dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "tblTelefone");

    objComm.ExecuteNonQuery(); //retorna o número de linhas afetadas 
    dataSet.Clear(); //limpa os dados no dataSet
    objConn.Close(); //encerra a conexão com o banco de dados 

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Então no caso eu vou precisar digitar a ID do cliente (que já existe da outra table) que eu quero adicionar o telefone?

Comment: isso depende da usabilidade da sua tela. Normalmente, voce seleciona o cliente que quer adicionar o telefone para, ao selecionar o cliente, voce tera o `ID` dele. (se voce nao selecionar o cliente, nao tem como atribuir o telefone para um cliente especifico)

Comment: sim, mas como voce nao colocou o codigo da sua grid, nao tenho como colocar. Ai coloquei um textbox como exemplo. mas é só voce trocar pelo grid

Comment: eu atualizei, tem como dar uma olhada por favor?

Comment: voce ja esta jogando o valor para a variavel `contatoID`, ou o `IDCli_atual` dependendo em qual dos dois voce esta armazenando seu codigo do cliente

Comment: Deu erro referecia de objeto não definida para uma instancia de um objeto

Comment: no momento que voce vai executar o codigo de inserção, a sua variavel `contatoID` deve estar com o valor preenchido, para que isso aconteca, vc deve ter selecionado a linha antes (no caso ter clicado no `dgvTable_Contato`) pra poder carregar essa variavel.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55542/discussion-between-andrepaulo-and-bellon).

Comment: pode ver o chat por favor?